# Trigger Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have an autocomplete input to search clients. Also i have a button to add new client whith a modal. When the client is saved in the DB, i send the var with the name and last name direct to de textfild to be selected. This works ok, only that the autocomplete doesn't search until i delete at least 1 char.

I use this to fill autocomplete field:

```
document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=JSON.parse(data).nombre;
```

It fills ok but not trigger the search.

Here is the script:

```
$("#nombre_aut").autocomplete({

     source: "cliente_data.php",
     minLength: 3,
     select: function( event, ui) {

        }
});

 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#insert_clt_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
             $.ajax({  
                     url:"insertar_clt.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_clt_form').serialize(),  
                        success:function(data){  

                          $('#nuevo_usuario_modal').modal('hide');  
                         document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=JSON.parse(data).nombre;
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#nombre_aut').val(JSON.parse(data).nombre).change();
```

change() triggers the change.  Without it, anything you dio won't trigger the change receiver function.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt work. Autocomplete is filled but not triggered...

Comment: Just changed it a little more, but I don't think you were changing the value correctly, first of all, but after the value is changed programatically, you have to trigger the change() function to make any events looking for the change react.

Here is an example, showing how you don't get an alert until the change function is called.

https://jsfiddle.net/29ts024y/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nombre_aut').autocomplete('search', $('#nombre_aut').val())
```

Just added this after `document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=JSON.parse(data).nombre;`